# Load a view block into a custom page generated in a module

Tags: views, 8, blocks

Is it possible to programatically insert an existing view into a block generated by a custom module and pass it a parameter?

I am generating a block based on some external api data. I have been asked to add a view that pulls in related content from the website. To do this I would like pass a view to my block and pass it a parameter I extract from the api data.

Can this be done, and if so... how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just like in D7, using [views_embed_view](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!views!views.module/function/views_embed_view/8.2.x).

```
print views_embed_view('view_name','machine_name', $parameter);
```

In case you are wondering, this is the [machine_name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JDJ1q.jpg)

Example:

```
$parameter = 1;
print views_embed_view('hello_world','block_1', $parameter);
```